# How to do this select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I must perform this operation under oracle 9 and sql server 9

I have on table with images inside and it can be quite heavy.
I want to select the ten first rows then the ten next etc... until the end of the table.
If possible I would like to have the same request to do that for oracle and sql server for maintenance reasons. I saw things like rownum and stuff but I didn't understand how it works and if it suits what I have.

Thx for your help.

Comment: Always lift with the knees for heavy items

Comment: By "heavy" do you mean large, slow and/or expensive to query?  Please explain your situation, what you are trying to achieve and what outcome you want.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the mistake, it's sqlserver 2005.
And i meant expensive to retrieve, the pictures can be over 1 Mb.

Comment: If i could just add an offset i can modify and select 10 lines it would be good.

Comment: What do you mean by "first ten rows"?  SQL tables represent unordered sets, so there is no concept of "first ten rows".  You need another column to specify this.

Comment: getting the rows ten by ten. for the entire table.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following in both Oracle and SQL Server:

```
with cte as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from table t
     )
select cte.*
from cte
where seqnum between X and Y;
```

You need to plug in the values of X and Y for each call.

This assumes that SQL Server 9 really means SQL Server 2005+.  I don't recognize SQL Server 9 as a valid version (see [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-versions) for a list of versions).

Comment: If by "heavy" the OP means the table is large and expensive to query a pagination routine like this would still be very expensive.

Comment: Imagine there's 10Gb of pictures